# Making windows application visible to browser

Tags: c#, windows, browser, file-type

Background info:
I have a windows application (in c#) that handles a custom file type which is just a wrapper for .pdf and .doc files. The user has to download and install this program from the website in order to view and edit their custom file types and save them back to the server.

Question:
Is there any way to make sure when a file is downloaded the application starts and opens the file by altering the install files of the application? I have been looking through the MSDN documentation on file types and it is registered but I couldn't find a handler for On Download. Any guidance is useful, I'm new to stackoverflow and c#.

Comment: type "associate extension c#" in the top-right stackoverflow search box for answers.

Comment: @alex ya, I've read through that stuff but it is all about getting a file type associated with an executable, it seems to me, which I already have done. What I want is to be able to download the file and automatically open it without having to click on it or find it in downloads.

Comment: That's a behavior that must be setup in the user's browser, you have no control over it as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to register a mime type on the computer during your install process. Then you will need to send the corresponding mime type with the download.

Here is some basic info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775148(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The installer registers the MIME type on installation, in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. But how do I get the file to open on download?

Comment: With the content-type and content-disposition headers.

Comment: Won't that prompt the user for a Save As, and then just save the file with no further action? Sorry, I'm not quite grasping the concept yet.

Comment: The dialog should also have an 'Open' choice which would then use your application. I don't know if there is a way to do it without the dialog.

Comment: What about for Chrome? if content-type=application\<extension> and content-disposition=attachment;filename=<filename> , Chrome just downloads the file and doesn't prompt for an open.